# Python - SQLite - Issue with a query not working properly

Tags: python, sqlite

This block of code takes user input and uses it to update information in a database.

```
def Update_Save_Button(self, event = None):
    ticketinfo2 = self.ticketeu2.get()
    ticketinfo3 = self.ticketeu3.get()
    ticketinfo4 = self.ticketeu4.get()
    ticketinfo5 = self.ticketeu5.get()
    ticketinfo6 = self.ticketeu6.get()
    if  len(ticketinfo2) == 0 or \
        len(ticketinfo3) == 0 or \
        len(ticketinfo4) == 0 or \
        len(ticketinfo5) == 0 or \
        len(ticketinfo6) == 0:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please check that all fields have been entered.")
    else:
        self.cursor.execute ('''
                            UPDATE 
                                "Service Tickets"  
                            SET
                                "Reason for Visit" = ?,
                                "WarrantyVPO" = ?,
                                "Date Ticket Received" = ?,
                                "Date of Service" = ?,
                                "Service Person" = ?
                            WHERE
                                "ServiceTicketsId" = ?;
                            ''',
                            (ticketinfo2, ticketinfo3, ticketinfo4, ticketinfo5, ticketinfo6, self.text1,))
        self.con.commit()
        self.Tree_Refresh   (self.SecondTree, 
                                ('''
                                SELECT 
                                    * 
                                FROM
                                    "Service Tickets"
                                WHERE 
                                    JobID = ?
                                '''),
                                (self.JobID,))
        self.LoadUpdate.destroy()
```

I have many other blocks of code where queries are being run, and they all run correctly.  This block of code, however, is not operating correctly.  Not only that, but there are no errors being yielded in the terminal.  I have had issues with improper syntax in the past with previous queries, and I tried to use what I learned to fix the current problem.  I have also tried adding, moving, and removing lines of code.  I would include specifics, but unfortunately I've done so much that I lost track of what all I've tried.

I will say, however, that when I removed the WHERE section of my query, the UPDATE worked.  It updated all of the data in the table, albeit some of the data appeared to be incorrect.

I would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0):

since removing "WHERE" clause from UPDATE statement makes it to update all the rows, I'd assume the condition "ServiceTicketsId = ?" is always false. Check the parameter value and make sure "self.text1" (I believe this is the value you are passing over to WHERE-clause) contains an existing ticket id.

Comment: Hey ekochergin.  I have already printed self.text1 and have seen that it does in fact contain an existing ticket id at the time the program is being run.

Answer (score 0):

Annoyingly enough, the solution was to convert self.text1 to a string

```
else:
        self.text1 = str(self.text1)
        self.cursor.execute ('''
                            UPDATE 
                                "Service Tickets"  
                            SET
                                "Reason for Visit" = ?,
                                "WarrantyVPO" = ?,
                                "Date Ticket Received" = ?,
                                "Date of Service" = ?,
                                "Service Person" = ?
                            WHERE
                                "ServiceTicketsId" = ?;
                            ''',
                            (ticketinfo2, ticketinfo3, ticketinfo4, ticketinfo5, ticketinfo6, self.text1,))
```